# Sprite-Kit Scene Scrolling - Objective-C / iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I am creating an iphone game where you fly a moon lander around over terrain. The background image and the terrain are the same and I've wrapped the terrain in a collision boundary.

Im using an ipad in landscape mode and the background/terrain that im using is 3x the width of the ipad screen.

I do not want to have an infinite scrolling map. what im trying to do is get it so that when the lander is within say 250 points of the left or right side of the screen the lander will not proceed farther then that and the back ground will scroll instead, still giving the illusion of movement.

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (touching) { // if the user is touching thrust node

        CGVector movement = [self getVectorFromRotation:lander.zRotation andMagnitude:12000];

        if (lander.position.x > self.frame.size.width - 250) {

            // move the background here.?
            // example appreciated!

    } else {

            [lander.physicsBody applyForce: movement ];

    }
}

-(CGVector)getVectorFromRotation:(float)radians andMagnitude:(int)mag{


    float x = -mag * sin(radians);

    float y = mag * cos(radians);

    return CGVectorMake(x, y);
}
```

obviously I need to stop when there is no more image to scroll on to the screen and if I go back the other direction the background shouldn't move until I come within 250 points of one of the sides.

Unfortunately the ONLY things I cant find on screen scrolling are where the "player" sprite is fixed to one position and I want freedom of movement except when within 250 points of each side.

all help is appreciated.

Comment: I can see how this can be done but it will not work with your current code logic. You use applyForce: to move your lander which is fine for a physics object but your background is not a physics object. This means that you cannot easily combine the movement of your background based on the movement of your lander object. You could do it if you picked one or the other but you want both - ranged object movement and background movement. To do what you want you will have to change your code logic to moving your lander by a non physics way. Example: x=x+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Unable to get the desired effect in sprite kit due to using the physics engine. This could have been achieved in other ways but i was to far along to re-write all of my code.

In this instance i had to use code that simply made the background move at a constant speed.